# How to setenv as PWD?

Tags: linux, csh

I'm trying to set my JAVA_HOME using : setenv JAVA_HOME 'pwd' , however , it sets it as pwd , rather than the actual path we get using pwd . 
I know it might be a stupid question but I'm an absolute newbie to Linux. Using CSH.
Is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks instead of quotes:

```
setenv JAVA_HOME `pwd`
```